# Unable to have Bash-like C-x-e in Zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

I found the following command in Bash which Zsh does not have in the same buttons at the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784019/how-can-i-invoke-vim-with-c-x-e-for-long-complex-tricky-commands).

```
Ctrl-x-e
```

It opens the current input in terminal to an editor.

**How can you have the same command in Zsh?**

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm using it with VIM mode. Basically ESC-v (or simply v if already in command mode) opens the terminal. It is setup by:

```
autoload -U edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Here is how to setup it in emacs mode:

```
autoload edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^Xe' edit-command-line
```

Use 'bindkey -e’ to to enable emacs style or ‘bindkey -v’ to enable vi style.

Comment: Is the command for Emacs mode Ctrl-X-e? It did not work for me in terminal.

Comment: It's Ctr-x, then e. You could change '^Xe' to '^X^e' if it is Ctrl-x ctrl-e what you want. Be sure to turn on emacs style (although it is the zsh default) by simply: bindkey -e alone in a line.

Comment: @emg-2: It works. Thank you! I had a corrupted shell script which Zsh did not give any alert. I get an alert about it in Bash.

Comment: What do the first 2 lines do? Can I get away with just setting `bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line` with my other bindkeys?

Comment: This is absolutely delicious! Thank you for teaching my zsh how to do what I missed most from my stock bash days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sublime as your editor then make sure you have `-w` option added in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file, otherwise it may won't work.

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```